# how to hide a div in php else statement

Tags: php

> samcheckdb.php

```
  $sql1="select subtitle,descript from dessert where itemId='oepd1007'"; 
  $result1=mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql1);
  $sql2="select subtitle,descript from dessert where itemId='oepd5148'"; 
  $result2=mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql2);

<div id="d0"><?php  if($result1) { echo $descript1 ;} ?></div>
<div id="s0"><?php  if($result1) { echo $subtitle1 ;} ?></div>
<div id="d11"><?php if($result2) {echo $descript2; } ?></div>
<div id="s11"><?php  if($result2) { echo $subtitle2 ;} ?></div>
```

> customer

```
 <html>
 <li><a href="samcheckdb.php">    <img src="getdesserticecreamimage.php?itemId=oepd1007" alt="image" id="img1" onclick="get_detail('oepd1007');"></a></li> 
<li>  <a href="samcheckdb.php"><img src="getdesserticecreamimage.php?itemId=oepd5148" alt="image" id="img2"></a></li> 
 </html>
```

> i need to display only 1 subtitle and descript in the page at a time, when the user clicks on the image,only the corresponding info of the particular image get displayed,not the rest..

Answer (score 3):

another neater approach is to use the : block

```
<?php if ($result1): ?>
    <div id="d0"><?php echo $descript1 ; ?></div>
    <div id="s0"><?php echo $subtitle1 ; ?></div>
<?php elseif($result2): ?>
    <div id="d11"><?php echo $descript2 ; ?></div>
    <div id="s11"><?php echo $subtitle2 ; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if($result1) { ?>
   <div id="0"><?php echo $descript1; ?></div>
   <div id="s0"><?php echo $subtitle1; ?></div>
<?php } else { ?>
   <div id="d11"><?php echo $descript2; ?></div>
   <div id="s11"><?php echo $subtitle2; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: plese tel me how to hide div in else part

Answer (score 0):

Always remember that you can echo all HTML Elements in PHP.

```
<?php 

if($result1) { 
echo '<div id="d0">' . $descript1 .'</div>';
echo '<div id="s0">' . $subtitle1 .' </div>';
} 
if($result2) { 
echo '<div id="d11">' .  $descript2 .'</div>';
echo '<div id="s11">' .  $subtitle2 .'</div>';
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
echo (isset($result1) ?  '<div id="d0">'. $descript1 .'</div><div id="s0">'.$subtitle1 .'</div>': '<div id="d11">'.$descript2 .'</div><div id="s11">'.$subtitle2 .'</div>');
```